# Algorithm - Initialize a random array in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

For some kid game, I have an array of size 10 of bool type.
I got a random number between 1 to 10 and what I like to do, Is initialize only that number of cells in TRUE but in random order.

For example, If my random number is 4, I would like outputs like:

```
F T F F F T T F F T
T F F T T T F F F F
```

Is there an easy way to do it in C#?

Note, I know all the syntax (Init an array, work with random and all), I have a problem to find a short algorithm that does it.

Comment: I'd do this in two steps: 1) generate the array by populating the right number of items of each type in a simple way; 2) shuffle the array. There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow about shuffling. (In particular, search for Fisher-Yates shuffles.)

Comment: Random int, for loop, random index. job done

Comment: If your number is 4, you want 4 random indices into the array, making sure to skip the indices that give a position where you already set a cell to `true`. That looks like an algorithm to me.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton I used your suggestion on shuffling. It works great (I'm new so I think I can't upvote you)

Answer (score 3):

Generate:

```
int length = 10;
int numberOfTrue = 4;

bool[] array = Enumerable
  .Range(0, length)
  .Select(index => index < numberOfTrue)
  .ToArray();
```

And [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (e.g. with Fisher–Yates algorithm):

```
Random random = new Random();

...

for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 1; --i) {
  int from = random.Next(i + 1);

  var h = array[i];
  array[i] = array[from];
  array[from] = h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like in real life, create the number of `true`s you want, the number of `false`s that you need and then put them in a bag and shuffle them:

```
var random = new Random();
int numberOfTruths = 7;
int numberOfFalsehoods = 10 - numberOfTruths;

var truths = Enumerable.Repeat(true, numberOfTruths);
var falsehoods = Enumerable.Repeat(false, numberOfFalsehoods);

var arrayOfBools = truths.Concat(falsehoods).OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();
```

Comment: While I approve of the general approach, there are better ways of shuffling - there are lots of examples in other questions.

Comment: [Don't sort by random](https://ericlippert.com/2011/01/31/bad-comparisons-part-four/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you don't want to use lists.

```
var rndBoolArray = new bool[10];

Random rnd = new Random();
int rndTrueCount = rnd.Next(1, 10); // Generate random number for the amount of true values in the array

for(int i = 0; i < rndTrueCount; i++)
{
    int rndIndex = rnd.Next(0, 9); // Generate random number for the index

    if(rndBoolArray[rndIndex] == false) // If the value at this position is not already true
        rndBoolArray[rndIndex] = true;
    else
        rndTrueCount++; // We have to do one more loop, if the value of the array at the random index was already true
}
```